# Touch-screen, 3 H-bridges and 3 sensors on Arduino Nano 3.0

Tags: arduino-nano, h-bridge

I am using an Arduino Nanao andI am wondering if there is a way to connect an 2 inch touchscreen, 3 H-bridges (it takes 3digital pins to power one of them and 1 additional to control the voltage) and have 3 analog pins left for sensors?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that there is at least one I2C touchscreen (eg. https://www.adafruit.com/product/1947 )(I2C need 2 pins - SCL(A5)+DATA(A4) - given by HW) and if you need 3x3=9 digital pins for setting direction, you can use also I2C multiplexer on the same 2 pins (http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/I2CPortExpander8574). So you are left with need for 3 PWM pins from (D3,D5,D6,D9,D10,D11).

So there is a way for sure.